# Running Notepad++ from Windows command prompt

Tags: path, environment-variables, command-prompt

I'm new to Windows (I'm using Windows 7 right now). I have downloaded Notepad++ and added the path `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe;` to the `PATH` environment variable. I quit the command prompt and opened it again, but when I type *notepad++* (or *notepadd++.exe*) it says

> 'notepad++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I checked the `PATH` again with the *echo* command and it shows the included path. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Here's the `PATH` value: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Encryption Clients\;C:\Users\orlowweyt\Downloads\apache-tomcat-8.0.42-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.42\bin;C:\Users\orlowweyt\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add the **directory** containing your *.exe* to the path instead.
Notice the existing entries in your path environment variable for example.

I.e. add this to your path:

```
C:\Program Files\Notepad++
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks @LukeDavies.